# Harmonic progression sum c++ openMP

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, openmp

I'm trying to make a parallel version of "Harmonic Progression Sum" problem using opemMP.
But the output are differents each other depending on the inputs. (Parallel and Sequential)

**Program:**

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <omp.h>
#include <time.h>

#define d 10    //Numbers of Digits (Example: 5 => 0,xxxxx)
#define n 1000  //Value of N (Example: 5 => 1/1 + 1/2 + 1/3 + 1/4 + 1/5)

using namespace std;

void HPSSeguencial(char* output) {
    long unsigned int digits[d + 11];

    for (int digit = 0; digit < d + 11; ++digit)
        digits[digit] = 0;

    for (int i = 1; i <= n; ++i) {
        long unsigned int remainder = 1;
        for (long unsigned int digit = 0; digit < d + 11 && remainder; ++digit) {
            long unsigned int div = remainder / i;
            long unsigned int mod = remainder % i;
            digits[digit] += div;
            remainder = mod * 10;
        }
    }


    for (int i = d + 11 - 1; i > 0; --i) {
        digits[i - 1] += digits[i] / 10;
        digits[i] %= 10;
    }
    if (digits[d + 1] >= 5) {
        ++digits[d];
    }


    for (int i = d; i > 0; --i) {
        digits[i - 1] += digits[i] / 10;
        digits[i] %= 10;
    }
    stringstream stringstreamA;
    stringstreamA << digits[0] << ",";


    for (int i = 1; i <= d; ++i) {
        stringstreamA << digits[i];
    }
    string stringA = stringstreamA.str();
    stringA.copy(output, stringA.size());
}

void HPSParallel(char* output) {
    long unsigned int digits[d + 11];

    for (int digit = 0; digit < d + 11; ++digit)
        digits[digit] = 0;

    int i;
    long unsigned int digit;
    long unsigned int remainder;
    #pragma omp parallel for private(i, remainder, digit)
    for (i = 1; i <= n; ++i) {
        remainder = 1; 
        for (digit = 0; digit < d + 11 && remainder; ++digit) {
            long unsigned int div = remainder / i;
            long unsigned int mod = remainder % i;
            digits[digit] += div;
            remainder = mod * 10;
        }
    }

    for (int i = d + 11 - 1; i > 0; --i) {
        digits[i - 1] += digits[i] / 10;
        digits[i] %= 10;
    }
    if (digits[d + 1] >= 5) {
        ++digits[d];
    }

    for (int i = d; i > 0; --i) {
        digits[i - 1] += digits[i] / 10;
        digits[i] %= 10;
    }
    stringstream stringstreamA;
    stringstreamA << digits[0] << ",";

    for (int i = 1; i <= d; ++i) {
        stringstreamA << digits[i];
    }
    string stringA = stringstreamA.str();
    stringA.copy(output, stringA.size());
}

int main() {
    //Sequential Method
    cout << "Sequential Method: " << endl;
    char outputSeguencial[d + 10];
    HPSSeguencial(outputSeguencial);
    cout << outputSeguencial << endl;

    //Cleaning vector
    string stringA = "";
    stringA.copy(outputSeguencial, stringA.size());

    //Parallel Method
    cout << "Parallel Method: " << endl;
    char outputParallel[d + 10];
    HPSParallel(outputParallel);
    cout << outputParallel << endl;

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

**Examples:**

***Input:***

```
#define d 10
#define n 1000
```

***Output:***

```
Sequential Method:
7,4854708606╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠
Parallel Method:
6,6631705861╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠ÇJ^
```

***Input:***

```
#define d 12
#define n 7
```

***Output:***

```
Sequential Method:
2,592857142857╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠ÀÂ♂ü─¨@
Parallel Method:
2,592857142857╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠ÇJJ
```

**Regards**

***Pastecode***

http://pastecode.org/index.php/view/62768285

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your threads step on each other's toes when updating the `digits` array. Hence some additions are lost, and you get bogus results (different results in different runs, almost certainly).

You must synchronise the writes to `digits`, e.g. with an atomic (or critical) section:

```
// ... <snip>
#pragma omp parallel for private(i, remainder, digit)
for (i = 1; i <= n; ++i) {
    remainder = 1; 
    for (digit = 0; digit < d + 11 && remainder; ++digit) {
        long unsigned int div = remainder / i;
        long unsigned int mod = remainder % i;
        #pragma omp atomic     // <- HERE, could also be #pragma omp critical
        digits[digit] += div;
        remainder = mod * 10;
    }
}
// <snip> ...
```

so that only one thread at a time can update the array. For a task like this, that would probably nullify any gains of splitting the task in several threads, though.

Comment: Some compilers (read GCC) implement atomic `+=` with `lock addl` on x86. Critical sections are implemented with mutexes, include run-time function calls and are thus way slower than atomics. Actually, since the inner loop is regular, threads would delay synchronise after several iterations and there would be no waiting. The cache coherency is what would hurt the parallel gain.

Answer (score 1):

As [Daniel Fischer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13388427/1380707) pointed out, you have a write conflict, but you can avoid it more elegantly than with an `omp critical` section, e.g. by giving each thread it's own copy of `digits` and aggregating them all at the end of the loop.

Comment: Even more elegant solution would be to rewrite the code in Fortran as OpenMP supports reductions over array variables in Fortran :)